# Exponent of a group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $1\to A\to B\to C\to 1$ be a short exact sequence of groups. Are there any nice formulas relating the exponent of $A$, $B$ and $C$? Is it true that exponent of $B$ is the product of exponents of $A$ and $C$?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Isn't the exponent of $C_4$ equal to the product of the exponents of $C_2$ and $C_2$ ($2\cdot 2=4$)?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I think you should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really meant "product," then the split exact sequence

$$1 \to C_2 \to C_2 \times C_2 \to C_2 \to 1$$

is a counterexample. If you meant "lcm," which is what the answer is for direct products, then the non-split exact sequence

$$1 \to C_2 \to C_4 \to C_2 \to 1$$

is a counterexample.

Comment: I think the most one can say is that it divides the product.

Comment: And it is divisible by the lcm of the exponents of $A$ and $C$.